# Linkedin access token for application that doesn't require a member to login

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Our application can show rich links to webpages. So instead of a mere weblink we show a short summary and a picture. We used to use embed.ly's extract api to supply us with this data, but since they have changed their terms and pricing we have implemented an alternative solution.
The problem we find is that linkedin profile urls cannot be assessed by our new solution. Embedly was able to give us all the details we needed from a linkedin profile url (including the user's picture), but we don't seem to have access to that information without going through linkedin's API.

This call gives us all the data we are looking for:

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=[PROFILE_URL]:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,summary,formatted-name,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),site-standard-profile-request,public-profile-url)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=[TOKEN]

Where [PROFILE_URL] is a linked in profile url and [TOKEN] is the oauth2 access token.

There are two issues that I have:

1. Our application does not ask users to authenticate through linkedin, so we do not have a user oauth2 access token available;
2. Linkedin's suggestion in their FAQ (https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq) seems very daft:

> Can I get an access token for my application that doesn't require a member to login?
>
> We do not provide access tokens for applications that are not associated with a particular LinkedIn member.
>
> If your application requires you to make API calls in an automated way - without user interaction, you need to bootstrap the first access token request by manually signing in, and then ensure that your application refreshes the token automatically prior to expiry to avoid the need for additional human authentication.

Now... four questions:

a. Has anyone implemented option [2] in a production setting?

b. If yes, what are the limitations, downsides etc. Is this really the best and safest solution?

c. Is there *any* alternative that allows me to authenticate the application itself with its mighty client key and client secret?

d. Is there anyone from linkedin monitoring this? If yes, can you contact me?

Cheers, Raymond

Comment: Did you find any solution?